# How to plot hours grouped by day

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe `mean_by_day_hour` with the following columns. I would like to plot the `volume` as an average per `hour` per `day`. Exactly like excel does with pivot tables. Is there a way to do so in Python/Matplotlib/Seaborn ?

```
     day  hour  volume
0    Mon     0  301.25
1    Mon     0  260.50
2    Mon     0  329.00
3    Mon     1  149.00
4    Mon     1  161.00
..   ...   ...     ...
499  Sun    22  722.00
500  Sun    22  857.00
501  Sun    23  600.25
502  Sun    23  457.00
503  Sun    23  510.00
```

I somewhat managed to do this by adding another column `time_interval` and by playing around with xticks labels.

```
     [day  hour  volume time_interval
0    Mon     0  301.25        Mon-0h
1    Mon     0  260.50        Mon-0h
2    Mon     0  329.00        Mon-0h
3    Mon     1  149.00        Mon-1h
4    Mon     1  161.00        Mon-1h
..   ...   ...     ...           ...
499  Sun    22  722.00       Sun-22h
500  Sun    22  857.00       Sun-22h
501  Sun    23  600.25       Sun-23h
502  Sun    23  457.00       Sun-23h
503  Sun    23  510.00       Sun-23h
```

The result is not as clean as I would like (2-axis) instead of one (first axis would be `hour` and second would be `day`). Also, it's not very automatic; when the dataframe size changes, I have to adjust the xticks labels again.

I would consider using seaborn because of the hue parameter but I'm also open to pyplot.

Here is my code for plotting

```
#Loc is to order by day of week, not relevant here
mean_by_day_hour = pd.pivot_table(df, values=["volume"], index=["day", "hour", "period"], aggfunc=np.mean).loc[get_day_names(df, "day_number")]
print(mean_by_day_hour)
mean_by_day_hour.reset_index(inplace=True)
#Workaround by creating time_interval column
mean_by_day_hour["time_interval"] = mean_by_day_hour["day"].astype(str) + "-" + mean_by_day_hour["hour"].astype(str) + "h"
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
sns.lineplot(x="time_interval", y='volume', hue="period", data=mean_by_day_hour, errorbar=None)
#df_list has the different dataframes: one per period
plt.xticks(mean_by_day_hour["time_interval"].iloc[0:int(len(mean_by_day_hour)/len(df_list)):12].index, mean_by_day_hour["time_interval"].iloc[0:len(mean_by_day_hour):12*len(df_list)].values)
plt.show()
```

[image: excel]

[image: what I tried doing]

Comment: Why don't you provide your existing code?

Comment: Had some issues with editing my post, the code is now there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe using the `groupby` method in the DataFrame will help you:

```
mean_by_day_hour.groupby(
    ["day", "hour"]
)[["volume"]].mean()
```

This will return a DataFrame with the mean volume for each day-hour pair, then you can use the `.plot()` method.

Comment: I tried your solution for each period. However, I don't end up getting and even axis. For example, ticks every 12 hours. Also, I can't seem to have 1st axis with hours and 2nd axis with days like in Excel. Regards.

Comment: @cotak regarding the axis ticks, matplotlib has functionality to customize how ticks should show. I've done it using the `Axes.xaxis.set_major_locator` method and the `matplotlib.ticker` module.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.groupby()`:

```
mean_by_day_hour.groupby(by=['day', 'hour']).mean()
```

which groups by the columns `day` and `hour`, and then takes the mean value per group

Comment: Very interesting solution. Not what I'm looking for though but very smart.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is to use `df.pivot_table(index='day', columns='hour', values='volume')`.

```py
pivot_data = df.pivot_table(index='day', columns='hour', values='volume')

# Heatmap
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
sns.heatmap(pivot_data, annot=True, fmt=".1f")
plt.show()
```